# How do I make a conversion from scientific notation more precise?

Tags: c++, c++11, scientific-notation

When I'm trying to convert a number from 1e+050 to its natural form it shows me 100000000000000007629769841091887003294964970946560 instead of 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000. How can I make that conversion more precise? Here's the code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
long double range, a, b;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
range = pow(10,50);
cout << "enter a and b" << endl;
cin >> a >> b;  
cout.setf(ios::fixed); 
if((a >= range)||(b >= range)||(a <= -range)||(b <= -range)){
    cout << "the number is too large" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "a+b= " << a + b << endl;
    cout << "a-b= " << a - b << endl;
    cout << "a*b= " << a * b << endl;
}
cout << range << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: A `long double` likely (depending on your exact environment) cannot represent `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. You will need to use either a decimal-based floating point value (i.e. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format) assuming compiler support) or a big-integer library that can handle such large integers, such as GNU MP or the Boost library discussed above.

Comment: @nanofarad: Sometimes it can. it's unspecified in C++ if `double` uses base2 or base10. base2 can't represent it, but base10 can :(

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah, I wasn't aware that base-10 floats were supported as part of the spec. Good to know!

Comment: @MooingDuck Are there really implementations that use base 10? That's crazy, and I'd love to read more about them.

Comment: @czescx No, there is no way to change the used base. It's defined by your machine. You're stuck with base 2 floating point. If you want to support numbers that large, you do need a big-integer library.

Comment: I will try with that Boost library. Thanks guys

Comment: @Justin good to know, thanks bro

Comment: The specification defines a power-of-ten format, but that doesn't imply that any useful implementations support it.

Comment: **Required reading:** [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Justin: That's what [`std::numeric_limits<double>::radix()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/radix) exists for, to tell you the "base" for your floating point numbers.

Comment: @MooingDuck I understand that. Do you know of any implementations which use base 10?

Answer (score 0):

The only numbers that can be precisely represented by `double` are those of which can be produced by multiplying or dividing an integer in the range +/-2⁵³ by an integer power of two.  The value 1E22 is 2,384,185,791,015,625 times 4,194,304, which is of that form (note that 2⁵³ is 9,007,199,254,740,992).  Powers of ten larger than that are not of that form.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned by other comments and answer, a double cannot represent the value that you want (i.e. 1e+50). But, if you only care about the displaying of this value, you can use a `std::stringstram` to display the big double in scientific format:

```
   stringstream strRange;
   strRange << range;

   cout << strRange.str() << endl;
```

and the output on both VS2015 and gcc 10.1 is:

```
range value is: 1e+50
```